# C# .NET Core 3.1 Entity Framework : include using where condition gives wrong output

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities parent/child want select them all using include.

When adding condition on child it return parents which have this condition only not all parents

My code:

Parent entity:

```
public class SecRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecRolePageAction> SecRole_SecRolePageAction { get; set; }
}
```

Child entity:

```
public class SecRolePageAction
{
    public virtual SecRole SecRole { get; set; }
    public long SecRoleID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Code:

```
var Q = Context.Set<SecRole>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
Q = Q.Include(O => O.SecRole_SecRolePageAction)
      // Child condition below
     .Where(O => O.SecRole_SecRolePageAction.Any(P => P.IsDeleted == false)
     .ToList();
```

Result: it returns just parent contain child has `IsDeleted = false` but any parent has no child it does not return

I need to return all parents any help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are selecting and including correctly. You may just need to modify your Where clause to check and see if your child collection is null/empty OR it has any children which have not been deleted.

Something like:

```
.Where(O => O.SecRole_SecRolePageAction.Count() == 0 || O.SecRole_SecRolePageAction.Any(P => P.IsDeleted == false))
```

Answer (score 2):

**@Keith.Abramo** alreay gave the right answer for this question.

Here is the test result with this solution.

```
        public List<SecRole> getSecRole()
        {
            var SecRoles = _context.SecRoles.Include(h => h.SecRole_SecRolePageAction)
                .Where(O => O.SecRole_SecRolePageAction.Count() == 0 || O.SecRole_SecRolePageAction.Any(P => P.IsDeleted == false)).ToList(); // include address table

            return SecRoles;
        }
```

Date Source of `SecRoles`:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "1",
    "SecRole_SecRolePageAction": [
      {
        "SecRoleID": "101",
        "IsDeleted": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "2",
    "SecRole_SecRolePageAction": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "3",
    "SecRole_SecRolePageAction": [
      {
        "SecRoleID": "301",
        "IsDeleted": "false"
      },
      {
        "SecRoleID": "302",
        "IsDeleted": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> Screenshot of test result with `Where`

[image]

Comment: Although you credit the answer to someone else, I have upvoted, based on your output and explanation.

Comment: Hi, @Simon Price, thanks for your encouragement. I really gained a lot from these Q&A in the same time.